# Why can't I use an if statement inside a select statement? Does anyone know another method?

Tags: sql-server, if-statement

```
Select b.ItemKey, a.CatKey, a.ParentKey, a.CatName, g.ItemID, c.UserFld1, c.UserFld3, c.UserFld5, f.UOMID, e.SizeValue
From dbo.timWebCategory a Inner JOIN
    dbo.timWebCategoryItem b ON a.CatKey = b.CatKey Inner JOIN
    mas500_app.dbo.timItem c ON b.ItemKey = c.ItemKey Inner JOIN
    dbo.cpsIMItemDetails d ON c.ItemKey = d.ItemKey Inner JOIN
    dbo.timItemSize e ON c.ItemKey = e.ItemKey Left JOIN
    dbo.timVolumeUOM f ON e.VolUOMKey = f.VolUOMKey Left JOIN
    mas500_app.dbo.vWebItem g ON c.ItemKey = g.ItemKey
Where a.Catkey = @Key
AND d.IntFlg = 1
If @color is not Null 
Begin
    AND c.UserFld1 = @color
End
Order By f.UOMID, e.SizeValue**
```

Returns this:
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.

Comment: The general rule (of predicate calculus) is that `IF x THEN y` is logically equivalent to `(NOT x) OR y`. Or more formally, `p -> q = ~p v q`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that...

```
Select b.ItemKey, a.CatKey, a.ParentKey, a.CatName, g.ItemID, c.UserFld1, c.UserFld3, c.UserFld5, f.UOMID, e.SizeValue
From dbo.timWebCategory a Inner JOIN
    dbo.timWebCategoryItem b ON a.CatKey = b.CatKey Inner JOIN
    mas500_app.dbo.timItem c ON b.ItemKey = c.ItemKey Inner JOIN
    dbo.cpsIMItemDetails d ON c.ItemKey = d.ItemKey Inner JOIN
    dbo.timItemSize e ON c.ItemKey = e.ItemKey Left JOIN
    dbo.timVolumeUOM f ON e.VolUOMKey = f.VolUOMKey Left JOIN
    mas500_app.dbo.vWebItem g ON c.ItemKey = g.ItemKey
Where a.Catkey = @Key
AND d.IntFlg = 1
AND (@color = c.UserFld1 OR @color is null)
Order By f.UOMID, e.SizeValue**
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn that "inside out". You can't conditionally insert the AND, you have to always say the AND, and you may then use if-else (or just an OR, like the other answer) to conditionally provide either the condition you want or just true/false.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `if` statement to control which statements are executed, but you can't use it to remove part of a query.

One reason that it's not built that way is that the execution plan for the query would be different depending on the input, so a new execution plan would have to be created each time and could not be resused.

There are different ways to handle this, like using the `isnull` function to compare the value to itself if the varaible is null:

```
AND c.UserFld1 = isnull(@color, c.UserFld1)
```

Or checking for null before comparing:

```
AND (@coor is null or c.UserFld1 = @color)
```

You can always put the `if` statement around the query, which would give you two versions of the query, each with a slightly better plan than checking the value when running the query. Sometime that's worth the duplication of the code:

```
If @color is not Null Begin

  Select b.ItemKey, a.CatKey, a.ParentKey, a.CatName, g.ItemID, c.UserFld1, c.UserFld3, c.UserFld5, f.UOMID, e.SizeValue
  From dbo.timWebCategory a Inner JOIN
    dbo.timWebCategoryItem b ON a.CatKey = b.CatKey Inner JOIN
    mas500_app.dbo.timItem c ON b.ItemKey = c.ItemKey Inner JOIN
    dbo.cpsIMItemDetails d ON c.ItemKey = d.ItemKey Inner JOIN
    dbo.timItemSize e ON c.ItemKey = e.ItemKey Left JOIN
    dbo.timVolumeUOM f ON e.VolUOMKey = f.VolUOMKey Left JOIN
    mas500_app.dbo.vWebItem g ON c.ItemKey = g.ItemKey
  Where a.Catkey = @Key
    AND d.IntFlg = 1
    AND c.UserFld1 = @color
  Order By f.UOMID, e.SizeValue

End Else Begin

  Select b.ItemKey, a.CatKey, a.ParentKey, a.CatName, g.ItemID, c.UserFld1, c.UserFld3, c.UserFld5, f.UOMID, e.SizeValue
  From dbo.timWebCategory a Inner JOIN
    dbo.timWebCategoryItem b ON a.CatKey = b.CatKey Inner JOIN
    mas500_app.dbo.timItem c ON b.ItemKey = c.ItemKey Inner JOIN
    dbo.cpsIMItemDetails d ON c.ItemKey = d.ItemKey Inner JOIN
    dbo.timItemSize e ON c.ItemKey = e.ItemKey Left JOIN
    dbo.timVolumeUOM f ON e.VolUOMKey = f.VolUOMKey Left JOIN
    mas500_app.dbo.vWebItem g ON c.ItemKey = g.ItemKey
  Where a.Catkey = @Key
    AND d.IntFlg = 1
  Order By f.UOMID, e.SizeValue

End
```